# MySQL: Combine multiple row values into single column?

Tags: mysql

**Database: MySQL**

**Table: Teams**

```
TeamID    INT
TeamName  VARCHAR(20)
```

**Table: People**

```
PeopleID   INT
FirstNameID INT
LastNameID  INT
```

**Table: TeamMembers**

```
TeamID  INT
PeopleID  INT
```

**Table Example: Teams**

```
TeamID       TeamName
1            Team Xstream
2            Team INsanity
```

**Table Example: People**

```
PeopleID   FirstNameID   LastNameID
1          1351          453
2          5463          763
3          976           8762
4          87            784
5          187           465
6          761           566
7          376           2134
```

**Table Example: TeamMembers**

```
TeamID       PeopleID
1            1
1            3
1            7
2            2
2            4
2            5
2            6
```

**Desired Output:**

```
TeamName       TeamMembers
Team Xstream   John Smith/Jane Doe/Daniel Davis
Team INsanity  Sally Sue/Tom Thomas/Jack Jones/Harry Henderson
```

There will not be a set number of TeamMembers per team, so it's not like I could have three subqueries because there will only be three team members.  I've lightly looked online, but I always get the best and most thorough answers here.  Any ideas or pointers, please let me know.  I honestly have no idea where to begin here.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am guessing that the names of the people are actually stored somewhere considering you are just showing ID numbers as names.  But you will want to use both `CONCAT()` and [`GROUP_CONCAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) for this result.  The first step, will join all of the tables and use the `CONCAT()` function:

```
select t.teamname,
 concat(p.FirstNameId, ' ', p.LastNameId) teamMembers
from teams t
left join teammembers m
  on t.teamid = m.teamid
left join people p
  on m.peopleid = p.peopleid;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/37af9/8), which will produce the result:

```
|      TEAMNAME | TEAMMEMBERS |
-------------------------------
|  Team Xstream |    1351 453 |
|  Team Xstream |    976 8762 |
|  Team Xstream |    376 2134 |
| Team INsanity |    5463 763 |
| Team INsanity |      87 784 |
| Team INsanity |     187 465 |
| Team INsanity |     761 566 |
```

Once you have the data, then apply the `GROUP_CONCAT()` function and `GROUP BY` the teamname:

```
select t.teamname,
  group_concat(concat(p.FirstNameId, ' ', p.LastNameId) SEPARATOR '/') teamMembers
from teams t
left join teammembers m
  on t.teamid = m.teamid
left join people p
  on m.peopleid = p.peopleid
group by t.teamname;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/37af9/7)

results:

```
|      TEAMNAME |                     TEAMMEMBERS |
---------------------------------------------------
| Team INsanity | 761 566/87 784/187 465/5463 763 |
|  Team Xstream |      976 8762/376 2134/1351 453 |
```

Comment: Wow, that was fast.  Yes, you are correct that the people names are stored in another table.  I may be trying to rationalize my database too much by doing so, but since there will be millions of records, I thought this might be best.  It seems the Group_Concat will work.  Thanks.

Comment: @XstreamINsanity I am not sure the benefit you will have by storing the first/last name in a separate table. You will just have to perform additional joins, I suggest rethinking that design.

Comment: Well in reality it's actually going to be a database for sports cards.  There are many players that have names (first or last) that are the same.  And example would be 'Anthony' or 'James', etc.  So when creating the players table, instead of typing their names in, I wanted to use IDs from another table.  There may be only minimal gain from it, but I'm willing to go with it for now.

Comment: @XstreamINsanity Got it, well whatever will work for your situation.  Glad the query works for you.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't provide information on the table where names are actually stored, but what you are looking for is `GROUP_CONCAT` function. This is how you would use it to show the first and last name id's. I will leave it to you to join the name table and replace the name id fields in the query with the actual name fields.

```
SELECT t.TeamName, GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(p.FirstNameID, ' ', p.LastNameID))
FROM Teams as t
INNER JOIN TeamMembers as tm on t.TeamID = tm.TeamID
INNER JOIN People as p on tm.PeopleID = p.PeopleID
GROUP BY t.TeamName
```

By the way, normalizing the names out into their own table and using nameID seems like probably a good example of over normalization.  Why not just have name values in People table? This will save you adding a fourth table to your query (and possibly fifth table if first and last names are in different tables).